# How to filter out values by values in Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataFrame that I want to filter is:

```
         High    Low  Close    Volume
Date                                     
2014-06-02  634.8  622.5  628.6  13149746
2014-06-03  638.7  628.2  637.5  10419625
2014-06-04  647.9  636.1  644.8  11949821
2014-06-05  649.4  642.6  647.4  10657616
2014-06-06  651.3  644.5  645.6  12497800 
2014-06-09   93.9   91.8   93.7  74876982
2014-06-10   95.0   93.6   94.2  62458587
2015-06-11   94.8   93.5   93.9  45484122
```

I would like to select, for example from 2014-06-05 to the current date(2015-06-11). What's is the most proper way to select by comparing strings in the Date column?

Comment: Is Date a column or the index?

Comment: I am a absolute beginner to this framework. I did not use set_index('Date'), so I believe its a column. BTW, it fails when I try to call set_index('Date'), interpreter complains KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: What does `df.columns` output, this will tell you whether it's a column or not, it matters because the method of filtering will be different between columns and index value

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I got this
     Index([u'Open', u'High', u'Low', u'Close', u'Volume'], dtype='object')

Comment: This means that 'Date' is the index, is this what you want or not? You can call `reset_index()` if you want the date as a column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd convert the 'Date' column to dtype datetime so you can do date string comparison and then you can do the following:

```
In [26]:

df[(df['Date'] > '2014-06-05') & (df['Date'] < '2015-06-11')]
Out[26]:
        Date   High    Low  Close    Volume
4 2014-06-06  651.3  644.5  645.6  12497800
5 2014-06-09   93.9   91.8   93.7  74876982
6 2014-06-10   95.0   93.6   94.2  62458587
```

So first the conversion:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then the boolean condition requires using the `&` operator for `AND` and parentheses due to operator precedence.

**EDIT**

It looks like your 'Date' data is in fact the index, in which case you can still perform the datetime conversion like so: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` and then filter like this:

```
In [28]:

df[(df.index > '2014-06-05') & (df.index < '2015-06-11')]
Out[28]:
             High    Low  Close    Volume
Date                                     
2014-06-06  651.3  644.5  645.6  12497800
2014-06-09   93.9   91.8   93.7  74876982
2014-06-10   95.0   93.6   94.2  62458587
```